# Remove Android Button Black Border

Tags: android, android-button, android-styles

I am trying to figure out a way to remove the black border around an android button when pressed. I have specified a custom style for my buttons for the different button states, but nothing seems to remove the border that appears in the pressed state. This is my custom style:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:dither="true">

<item  android:state_pressed="true" >
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:color="@color/WhitePastel" android:width="0px"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/DarkGreenPastel"/>
</shape>
</item>
<item  android:state_enabled="false">
    <shape>
        <stroke android:color="@color/DarkGreenPastel" android:width="0px"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/DarkGreenPastel"/>
    </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:drawable="@color/GreenPastel"/>
</selector>
```

This is how it displays on runtime:
[image: The left button is pressed]

This is the xml for the selector:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/edu.utep.at.kiddieklock"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    tools:context=".MainMenuActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/InGameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/ClockAreaLinearLayout"
            android:layout_weight="7"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp">

            <kk.View.CaviarDreamsTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/time_challenge_title"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textColor="@color/WhitePastel"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                 custom:typeface="caviarDreamsBold"/>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="9"
                android:id="@+id/ClockGridLayout">

                <kk.View.ClockView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ClockView"/>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/clock_face"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

                <kk.View.CaviarDreamsTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text=""
                    android:id="@+id/TimerTextView"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="77dp"
                    android:textSize="40dp"
                    custom:typeface="caviarDreamsBold"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ImageButtonAreaGridLayout"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/WhitePastel"
            android:rowCount="1"
            android:columnCount="2">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/LeftButton"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="12:05"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                custom:typeface="caviarDreams"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/RightButton"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:text="7:30"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:onClick="buttonClicked"
                android:background="@drawable/green_button"
                />

        </LinearLayout>
      </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the xml where you used the selector

Comment: try setting `@android:color/transparent` for stroke color

Comment: @ABFORCE nop, didn't work.